# High quality answer to another question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, low-quality-posts

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40648766/4723795) in *LQPRQ*. I haven't faced that before so I'm here to ask the Community for the opinion.

1. There is a question which is answered.
2. Another user finds this topic and asks for a clarification of the accepted answer in a comment. He can't perform the setup.
3. New user posts another answer to the topic which answers that question from point 2. The answer would be a high quality answer if it was posted on another question. The question posted in a comment.
4. The answer was posted 3 weeks after the comment was added.

I find this situation unusual. Being strict I would recommend deletion. Being responsible reviewer I wouldn't flag it as `Looks OK` as it's irrelevant. On the other hand those two answers (Accepted and the subject of this question) together might help someone in the future as one describes set up to the other.

Personally I think that it should be deleted but I'm interested if you would have same doubts.

Stijn has clarified my doubt in a comment here: *I'm afraid of encouraging such "behaviour"*

Comment: @Stijn would you notify the author of the comment that someone responded to his comment?

Comment: @Stijn exactly! I think that my only doubt was about *encouraging such "behaviour"*

Comment: I've reposted the comments as an answer.

Comment: You may want to recommend creating new question out of that comment,  link back from original question and provide self-answer. You can even do it yourself (with CW answer giving appropriate attribution to original author). Something like "I tried steps in q .... but have issues with ...".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would flag it as not an answer (and have done so now), and it should be deleted.

It's up to the original answerer to respond to comments, and if the commenter really wants an answer to their question, they should post a new question. Better to not encourage such "behaviour".